# about redirecting from one view to another view in a multiview

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to redirect from one view to another view in a multiview on the same page at a button click event, so can anyone help, please.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Set the ActiveViewIndex property of MultiView As Below.

```
MultiView1.ActiveViewIndex = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use SetActiveView Method to target your desired view.

```
 protected void ButtonClick(object sender, Eventargs e)
 {
    MultiView.SetActiveView(ViewName);
 }
```

This will work even if you change your view position or index because it will target the specified view directly regardless its index or position within Multiview.